# How to set "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" on command line

Tags: command-line, update-manager, system-settings

How can I switch on the option to be notified for a new Ubuntu version, which you usually find in

> Dash --> System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Updates --> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`

from command line to `never`?

Comment: Try `sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

Comment: @mikewhatever thank you for this. Can you make an answer based on using sed to do it all automatically without manual editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it from command line.

```
sudo sed -i 's/=lts/=never/g' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Comment: The `g` flag is not necessary here. Just `'s/=lts/=never/'` should suffice.